# How to name a cshtml file for displaying a content part that has been created from admin UI in Orchard cms?

Tags: orchardcms

Suppose that I have created a content part in Admin UI with name "aaa" and attached it to an existing content type with name "bbb".

Now I want to add a .cshtml file in View folder of TheThemeMachine for displaying and customizing view of this part,  not the type.

I know I can add Content-bbb.cshtml for the ContentType but it isn't what I want because there may be several types use this part and I have to add single file for all of them.

**What should I name the cshtml file?**

I have been tested below names:
Parts.aaa, Parts-aaa, Parts_aaa, Parts.aaa-bbb, Parts.bbb-aaa, 
Parts.aaa.bbb, Parts.bbb.aaa
and many more

I do appreciate for any help.

This is the link of this question in codeplex:
https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/581243

Comment: I think Parts.aaa.cshtml and Parts/aaa.cshtml are both correct. Are you sure that is your current enabled theme?

Comment: Yes I have just "TheThemeMachine" theme and it is enabled, moreover the Content-bbb.cshtml and other files works fine.

Comment: Then I suggest  using the Shape Tracing feature (module) to check for the correct alternate

Comment: Thank you. I had used that tool but it just helps to create view for each fields of the part like Fields.Common.Text-aaa.cshtml or Fields.Boolean-aaa.cshtml not for the part. Although in any of this files the total model of part is accessible but this repeats for every field so it's unusable.